# Weird lighting problems in video?

Tags: light

There might be an answer somewhere else but I can't find it. 
You can't add videos here so here's a picture of the lighting problem:

[image: Problem]

It's fine at the beginning of the video but then it starts flashing and has the line down the plane.

My lighting is sun lamp and an environment texture.

[image]

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is you ground mesh duplicated? Sounds like Z-Fighting

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise no it's not :/

Comment: Worked it out. I subdivided the plane and put the sun on multiple importance. I don't know which fixed it but I'm not having the problem any more

Comment: That's odd.. If you still want an explanation, is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: @gandalf3 to upload the .blend do I need to link a Dropbox or blend swap or can you do it within the website?

Comment: you can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @Chickenator [Including a .blend file](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/658/2217)

Comment: Added a .blend if anyone wants to try work out what was wrong

Comment: Hm.. It doesn't appear to be happening for me in the .blend you uploaded, even after unsubdividing the plane and disabling MIS.

Comment: @gandalf3 did you only render the first frame or did you do the others?

Comment: I looked through most of the frames in viewport render and rendered the last frame, but no artifacts..

Comment: @gandalf3 maybe it had something to do with some compositing. Try adding a despeckle with 0 on both sliders and then add a soften with 1 fac and see if it still shows up. I can't check right now because I'm rendering

Comment: @Chickenator That had no effect.. Oh well, If it's not happening, then I guess alls well that ends well..